# Error serialising simple string to BSON using NewtonSoft Json.Net

Tags: serialization, json.net, bson

I am trying to serialize a simple string to BSON but I continually get this error;

"Error writing String value. BSON must start with an Object or Array. Path"

Can I not serialize a 'String' or simple type to BSON using Json.Net? if not why?

e.g.;

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var bw = new BsonWriter(ms))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        serializer.Serialize(bw, "Testing123");

        bw.Flush();
    }

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quoted](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) from bsonspec.org

> BSON is a binary format in which zero or more key/value pairs are
>   stored as a single entity. We call this entity a *document*.

This means that valid BSON must only be in the form of key/value pair, so writing simple value such as string or integer as a BSON document is not possible.

For why arrays can get through as a complete BSON document, here is the description quoted from the same source in Notes section:

> Array - The document for an array is a normal BSON document with
>   integer values for the keys, starting with 0 and continuing
>   sequentially. For example, the array `['red', 'blue']` would be encoded
>   as the document `{'0': 'red', '1': 'blue'}`. The keys must be in
>   ascending numerical order.